# eglibc-2.16 libc.so missing ruserok

Tags: build, compilation, glibc, configure, inet

I'm creating an optimized embedded linux system for two different ARM boards, A RaspberryPi and a Gumstix Overo, both of which are using eglibc-2.16 for the GNU C library.  But, I've noticed that my libc.so library for the RaspberryPi has ruserok, ruserok_af & iuserok symbols from the inet lib, but the libc.so library for my Gumstix Overo board doesn't contains those symbols.

I looked at the configure help output to see if I was missing a switch to include those symbols, but nothing jumped out at me.  Is there something special that I need to do to that I'm overlooking to get the inet library and all of its symbols compiled into libc.so?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Undefined reference to `ruserok`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890007/undefined-reference-to-ruserok-error).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by reconfiguring my OpenEmbedded build environment.