# ERROR: undefined reference to `ruserok` - while compiling PAM-1.1.8 for arm64

Tags: c, linux, musl

`.libs/pam_rhosts.o: In function pam_sm_authenticate:
pam_rhosts.c:(.text+0x1e4): undefined reference to ruserok'`

While compiling Linux-PAM-1.1.8 for arm64. I get this error.

ruserok is defined under a Macro check

```
    #ifdef __UCLIBC__
    ...
    ...
    ...
    int ruserok(const char *rhost, int superuser, const char *ruser,
                            const char *luser)
    {
      */ruserok defined here*/
    }
    ...
    ...
    #endif
```

But i am not building with Uclibc but with musl

What can i do now?

Comment: I suspect showing some code and telling us how you build this might make it easier to answer

Comment: You have probably forgotten to link with the right libraries. That is what "undefined reference" usually means.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [undefined reference to ruserok error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890007/undefined-reference-to-ruserok-error)

Comment: `What can i do now?` - provide your own definition of the symbol. Either patch the file or write your own. `even though ruserok is defined in pam_rhosts.c` - ruserok should be defined in the standard library, not in pam sources. It's a [standard function](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ruserok)

Comment: @KamilCuk Is there any other way without  disturbing the source like just linking Uclibc.

Comment: It's because `Uclibc` _doesn't_ provide ruserok, that pam needed to implement it itself. It looks like `musl` doesn't provide it either, so you could just remove the ifndef. Or add something along `#if defined(__UCLIBC__) || defined(__SOME_MACRO_THAT_MUSL_PROVIDSE_PROBABLY __MUSL__)`